# My alert dialog is returning a wrong value until I am forced to select something

Tags: android

I have a basic alarm dialog that I run the first time my app is loaded.  The alert is brought up when a option is selected in my "onOptionsItemSelected"  It loads up a list of times and has "30 seconds" selected by default "4".

But say the user just opens it and doesn't change any settings and clicks OK, "which" should make my "notificationChoice" 4 except it makes it 0.  Until I actually select a position "which" will return 0. When I pick a position press "OK", reopen the notification and just click OK I will get the correct result from "which".  Is this intended or am I doing something wrong?

```
    private void changeNotificationTimer() {

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String[] timeModes = { "10 Seconds.", "15 Seconds.", "20 Seconds.",
            "25 Seconds.", "30 Seconds.", "45 Seconds.", "1 Minute." };
    final int timerPos = settings.getInt("timerPos", 4);
    System.out.println("timerPos : " + timerPos);

    // Where we track the selected item
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle("Set Notification Timer");

    // Lets set up the single choice for the game mode.
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(timeModes, timerPos,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    notificationChoice = which;
                    System.out.println("which : " + which);
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    System.out.println("notificationChoice : " + notificationChoice);
                    // Set the shared prefs.
                    if (timerPos != notificationChoice) {
                        System.out.println(timerPos + " != " + notificationChoice);
                        setSharedNotificationPrefs(notificationChoice);
                    }

                }
            }).create().show();

}
```

Comment: Learn to use the debugger instead of using System.out().  You would find the problem in minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`onClick(DialogInterface, int)` is triggered when an option on the Dialog is clicked. It is not triggered when the user presses the positive button.

I am guessing that notificationChoice is `0` when the dialog is displayed and hence, `timerPos != notificationChoice`  passes and 0 is saved. You should be setting `notificationChoice` to `timerPos` before showing the dialog. And there's no need to check if `timerPos != notificationChoice`. Simply, save `notificationChoice`.

```
notificationChoice = timerPos;

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(timeModes, timerPos,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                notificationChoice = which;
                System.out.println("which : " + which);
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                System.out.println("notificationChoice : " + notificationChoice);
                // Set the shared prefs.

                System.out.println(timerPos + " != " + notificationChoice);
                setSharedNotificationPrefs(notificationChoice);


            }
        }).create().show();
```

Comment: I get error `notificationChoice` needs to be delared `final` because it's inner class, but how can I assign it in `setSingleChoiceItems` if `notificationChoice`  declared as `final` ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue.  I needed to set

```
notificationChoice = settings.getInt("timerPos", 4)
```

before the alert dialog so it can handle the option of no one selecting an option.